# How to select non-empty columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've been searching and can't find a solution to my simple problem.

I need to select all rows where a varchar column in it has text in it (letters, numbers, or special characters), so I wrote a query like the following:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

But this returns columns that contain the value '' (i.e. it's blank, but is not set to NULL so it still gets returned).

I tried changing the query to this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
AND col1 != ''
```

But that didn't work.

How do I stop the rows where the column is blank from being returned?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use `TRIM` there seems to be spaces in your column then

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
AND TRIM(col1) <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query if column is blank, but is not set to NULL

`SELECT col1 FROM table where col1 not like '';` # Two Single quotes without space

OR

This if column has one or more spaces,

```
SELECT col1 FROM table where col1 not like '% %';
```

Answer (score 1):

use **`LENGTH`** :

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(col1) > 0
```